# is countvectorizer thread safe?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, thread-safety, countvectorizer

I am using `sklearn` `countvectorizer` (4-words ngram) in my project, where I load an already fitted model and use it to transform a text. 
The methods I am using in my projects are: `transform`, `inverse_transform`, `vocabulary_.keys()`.

While using it, I realized that `inverse_transform` takes time (about 2.7 seconds for an instance) while the whole process takes about 3 seconds. After that, I inserted my model in a class that uses many threads (about 30 threads) to use this model with other models, I checked the time taken for this process only and I found that the time can be extended to 15 seconds.

My questions are:

1. Why does the process take much more time in the class?
2. Is count vectorizer thread safe? I couldn't find a clear answer to this question
3. If I replaced `inverse_transform` method with something else will this make the process in the class faster?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the code

```
for true_label, text in zip(labels, texts):
   splitted_text = text.split(" ")  # split text to remove features
   boolean_text = [False] * len(splitted_text)  # boolean list where the ith element is for the ith feature

   ngrams = list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(x), zip(splitted_text, splitted_text[1:], splitted_text[2:], splitted_text[3:])))
   doc_vocab = set(ngrams)
   non_religious_tokens = doc_vocab - set(vectorizer.vocabulary_.keys())
   print("non religious tokens:", non_religious_tokens)

   if len(splitted_text) > 3 and non_religious_tokens == set():
       print("Religious")
       print("--- prediction time: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
       continue

   print("******* 2nd Filter ********")
   # transform text
   vectorized_data = vectorizer.transform([text])
   terms = vectorizer.inverse_transform(vectorized_data)  # get features of text
   terms = terms[0]

   maybe_religious = not (len(terms) == 0)
   # for each feature
   for term in terms:

       splitted_term = term.split(" ")  # split term (splitted to four pieces in out case)

       # find 1st word index in text
       # match the other 3 words
       # set their indecies to true
       for i, word in enumerate(splitted_text):
           try:
               # find the piece of text that match this feature and highlight all the words as true (so they're removed
            #  later)
               if splitted_term[0] == splitted_text[i] and splitted_term[1] == splitted_text[i+1] and \
                    splitted_term[2] == splitted_text[i+2] and splitted_term[3] == splitted_text[i+3]:

                   boolean_text[i] = True
                   boolean_text[i+1] = True
                   boolean_text[i+2] = True
                   boolean_text[i+3] = True
           except IndexError:
               pass



   non_religious_text = ""
   # store non religious text (didn't match any feature in the text)
   for i, b in enumerate(boolean_text):
       if b is False:
           non_religious_text += " " + splitted_text[i]

   non_religious_text = remove_religious_stopwords(non_religious_text)

   # if all the features are removed, it's religious!
   if maybe_religious and (non_religious_text == "" or non_religious_text is None):
       print("Religious")
   # if the number of words remaining are lower than the limit
   # it's religious
   elif maybe_religious and (len(non_religious_text.split(" "))-1 <= max_non_religious):
       print("Religious")
   # other of that it's non religious
   else:
       print("Non Religious")


   print("--- prediction time: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Might be worth posting some of your code because what you're describing is quite an unusual pattern for using sklearn

Comment: @SvenHarris I just added the code, thanks

Comment: In general, the sklearn is not thread safe as far as I know. For the speed issues, there is a larger effort now to speed up sklearn. Then you may want to profile your code to see where most of the time is spent as well (i.e. is it really sklearn).